# Auto py to exe (Package Error,i have no clue what cause this error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, kivy, auto-py-to-exe

I am trying to compile my app with "Auto Py-to-Exe"
But when I try to compile it,I get an error (below the packages)

Package I used in my app :

Package                      Version

---

absl-py                      1.3.0

astunparse                   1.6.3

attrs                        22.1.0

cachetools                   5.2.0

certifi                      2022.9.24

charset-normalizer           2.1.1

contourpy                    1.0.5

cvzone                       1.5.6

cycler                       0.11.0

docutils                     0.19

flatbuffers                  22.9.24

fonttools                    4.38.0

gast                         0.4.0

google-auth                  2.13.0

google-auth-oauthlib         0.4.6

google-pasta                 0.2.0

grpcio                       1.50.0

h5py                         3.7.0

idna                         3.4

keras                        2.10.0

Keras-Preprocessing          1.1.2

Kivy                         2.1.0

kivy-deps.angle              0.3.2

kivy-deps.glew               0.3.1

kivy-deps.sdl2               0.4.5

Kivy-Garden                  0.1.5

kivymd                       1.1.1

kiwisolver                   1.4.4

libclang                     14.0.6

Markdown                     3.4.1

MarkupSafe                   2.1.1

matplotlib                   3.6.1

mediapipe                    0.8.11

numpy                        1.23.4

oauthlib                     3.2.2

opencv-contrib-python        4.6.0.66

opencv-python                4.6.0.66

opt-einsum                   3.3.0

packaging                    21.3

Pillow                       9.2.0

pip                          22.3

protobuf                     3.19.6

pyasn1                       0.4.8

pyasn1-modules               0.2.8

Pygments                     2.13.0

pyparsing                    3.0.9

pypiwin32                    223

python-dateutil              2.8.2

pywin32                      304

requests                     2.28.1

requests-oauthlib            1.3.1

rsa                          4.9

setuptools                   63.2.0

six                          1.16.0

tensorboard                  2.10.1

tensorboard-data-server      0.6.1

tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1

tensorflow                   2.10.0

tensorflow-estimator         2.10.0

tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.27.0

termcolor                    2.0.1

typing_extensions            4.4.0

urllib3                      1.26.12

Werkzeug                     2.2.2

wheel                        0.37.1

wrapt                        1.14.1

---

How to fix this error (below)

```py
3848 WARNING: lib not found: gstreamer-1.0-0.dll dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\lib\gstplayer\_gstplayer.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
3851 WARNING: lib not found: gobject-2.0-0.dll dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\lib\gstplayer\_gstplayer.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
3853 WARNING: lib not found: glib-2.0-0.dll dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\lib\gstplayer\_gstplayer.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
4274 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_utils.pyd
4316 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_transform_graph.pyd
4345 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_tfprof.pyd
4362 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_tensor_float_32_execution.pyd
4380 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_stat_summarizer.pyd
4395 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_nest.pyd
4411 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_kernel_registry.pyd
4426 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_determinism.pyd
4449 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_checkpoint_reader.pyd
4490 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\pywrap_saved_model.pyd
4517 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\internal\_pywrap_traceme.pyd
4545 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\internal\_pywrap_profiler.pyd
4588 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\_pywrap_stacktrace_handler.pyd
4628 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\_pywrap_record_io.pyd
4654 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\_pywrap_file_io.pyd
4682 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\grappler\_pywrap_tf_optimizer.pyd
4709 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\grappler\_pywrap_tf_item.pyd
4735 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\grappler\_pywrap_tf_cluster.pyd
4761 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_test_metrics_util.pyd
4782 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_op_gen.pyd
4806 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_api_parameter_converter.pyd
4832 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_api_info.pyd
4851 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_api_dispatcher.pyd
4886 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_proto_comparators.pyd
4911 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_op_def_util.pyd
4938 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_op_def_registry.pyd
4965 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_op_def_library_pybind.pyd
4992 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_errors_test_helper.pyd
5014 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_dtypes.pyd
5094 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\service\_pywrap_server_lib.pyd
5130 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_tf_session.pyd
5152 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_events_writer.pyd
5179 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_device_lib.pyd
5205 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_debug_events_writer.pyd
5540 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\core\_pywrap_py_func.pyd
5552 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Coding\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\core\_pywrap_bfloat16.pyd
```

I already try to reinstall the package, still the error prevails

Comment: i think i lost some dependency,but i dont have any idea to add it.Are i just do pip command like normal or i need to do something diffrent cause the error only happend in auto py to exe console,on my vscode console the program doing fine

Comment: I getexactly the same problem, I try to re-install tensorflow-cpu to reduce depedency, try onefile, and many walkaround with no sucess. Did you find a solution???

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to use `pyinstaller`
how do you use so many packages?

Comment: ... inside the app there is a machine learning that can read our hand gesture that what made there is so many packages(the package is over 1.5GB)